# How can I access the workflow ID in BeginOnSave / PersistenceIOParticipant?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, appfabric

I'm using PersistenceIOParticipant to write the workflow status to a custom db table. I need the workflow ID - any ideas how I can access it from within BeginOnSave?

Comment: Oh, by that I mean the ID of the current instance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the only way is to retreive it in a activity from the execution context and pass that to your service.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. That's frustrating.